# How to check if a particular word is present in a column of sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint 2007 list in which there is a column 'EmpID' which contains employee ids in this format: 12345;6789;121212

I need to find if 12345 is present in EmpID column. If i use caml query using asp.net It does not give me any result for only "12345".

If i enter whole data "12345;6789;121212" then only it gives me result. Please Help. I nees to search only 12345

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("URL"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                        SPList List = web.Lists["List Name"];
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                                       query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EMP_x0020_ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + TextBox1.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>";

                        SPListItemCollection items = List.GetItems(query);

                        DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();

                        if (dt==null)
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "No data";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                Label1.Text += r["Title"];
                            }

                        }
                }
```

}

Comment: Hi guys. it was so easy... use contains instead of EQ

Comment: Zeba - add this comment as an answer and then it can be marked as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was so easy... use contains instead of EQ